# AVPlayer keeps running in background how we stop it

Tags: ios, swift

I am using AVPlayer to play online videos. It is working fine. Now the problem is, when I pop out from the view before the videos starts playing, the background process keeps running. And when the videos gets loaded, it starts playing in background.

Comment: Why don't you stop loading and and assign nil to AVPlayer object?

Answer (score 0):

Before dismiss view pause player

```
if player != nil {
     player.pause()
     player = nil
  }
```

and also you need to pause player when your app goes to background

add this in your `viewDidLoad`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterBackground),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground,
                                               object: nil)
```

add this in your `viewController`

```
 @objc func applicationDidEnterBackground() {
        if player != nil {
           player.pause()
           player = nil
        }
 }
```

**By handling those both scenario you can stop player when you dismiss from that viewController also when your app goes into background**

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if self.player != nil {
            self.player.pause()
        }
    }
```